# Need help working ffmpeg in php

Tags: php, video, file-upload, ffmpeg

I am working on a video uploading site. I have never converted videos from other users though. All signs point towards using ffmpeg, but I am honestly lost. I have installed it properly within my htdocs folder in my xampp folder, and I have the upload file php setup correctly, because it does upload the video file and moves the file to the right folder. I do have what I would think to be working ffmpeg code within the php code, but it is not working. I need to make all the files .mp4 no matter what the input file format is. I would appreciate someone helping to figure out my problem so much.

"htdocs\new-video\upload\index.php" is where I have the code for ffmpeg and uploading the file. The htdocs\phpffmpeg\ folder is just the regular structure of phpffmpeg and ffmpeg installation.

This is the code for the uploading and ffmpeg exec.

```
        $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $extension = end($temp);

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
        "(my file location that I move the file to)" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

        shell_exec("ffmpeg -i $name.$extension -b 1500k -vcodec libx264 -vpre slow -vpre baseline -g 30 $name.mp4");
```

Like I said, the uploading and moving to folder works just fine. It is the not converting that is the problem. All links, tips, and information are greatly appreciated. Hope everyone has a great day.

Comment: A simpler way would probably be to use [Zencoder](https://zencoder.com/en/), the api is a lot simpler than FFMPEG.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell ffmpeg where the file is too.

e.g. you're doing:

```
$destination = '/some/path/on/your/server/kittens.mp4'
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $destination);
exec('ffmpeg .....    kittens.mp4');
                     ^---oops, no path
```

when it should be

```
exec('ffmpeg .... /some/path/on/your/server/kittens.mp4');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 shell_exec("cmd /c ffmpeg -i $name.$extension -b 1500k -vcodec libx264 -vpre slow -vpre baseline -g 30 $name.mp4");
```

if you gonna use a directory use C:\\